# c++ Occasional Dynamic Pointer Crashing

Tags: pointers, dynamic, while-loop, crash

I have made a program to take in float inputs from a user to create a dynamic array (Then use those inputs with functions to find basic stuff like max,min,sum,avg but that stuff works fine so I don't think Ill include that here for the purpose of not creating a wall of code).

It works about half the time and while I have some theories about the cause I cant put my finger on a solution.

```
int main() {
     int Counter = 0;
     float *UsrIn = nullptr;
     float Array[Counter];
```

My first thought was that the part below was the issue. My class hasn't really gone over what notation (I assume it refers to bytes so maybe scientific notation would work) to use with new that I can recall. I just tried 20 for the sake of testing and it seemed to work(probably a silly assumption in hindsight).

```
    UsrIn = new float[(int)20];
cout << "Enter float numbers:" << endl;
cout << "Enter '9999999' to quit:" << endl;
    cin >> *UsrIn;                  // User Input for pointer Dynamic Array
    Array[Counter] = *UsrIn;

while(*UsrIn!=9999999)              // User Input for Dynamic Array
    {
    Counter++;
    UsrIn++;
    cin >> *UsrIn;
    Array[Counter] = *UsrIn;
    }
delete UsrIn;
delete[] UsrIn;
```

My other thought was that maybe a pointer address was already in use by something else or maybe it was invalid somehow. I don't know of a way to test for that because the crash I occasionally get only happens when exiting the while loop after entering "9999999"

As a side note I'm not getting any warnings or error messages just a crashed program from eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable-length arrays are not universally supported in C++ implementations, although your compiler clearly supports them. The problem, from what you've described, is with this code:

```
int main() {
     int Counter = 0;
     float *UsrIn = nullptr;
     float Array[Counter];
```

You're defining a variable-length array of size 0. So, although you're allocating 20 entries for `UsrIn`, you're not allocating any memory for `Array`. The intention of variable-length arrays is to allocate an array of a given size where the size is not actually known until run time. Based on your other code, that's not really the situation here. The easiest thing to do is just change the `Array` size to match your `UsrIn` size, e.g.:

```
float Array[20];
```

If you really want more of a dynamic behavior, you could use `std::vector<float>`

```
std::vector<float> Array;
...
Array.push_back(*UsrIn);
```

Comment: Interesting to hear that using "Counter" in the way I tried isn't intended to be used that way. My class hasn't gone into vectors yet but I'll probably take a look at that out of curiosity. The thing is with array I wanted the user to be able to input any amount of inputs whether that be 2,20,or 200.

Comment: Standard array access doesn't do anything in terms of memory (re)allocation. `Array[3]` is just a shorthand for `*(Array + 3)`. The type of  dynamic behavior you're describing is precisely what the `push_back()` method of `std::vector` does. If more memory is required, it will reallocate.

Comment: BTW, if you find an answer helpful, please upvote it. If a post sufficiently answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. Thanks.